# Key binding for save all

Tags: sublime-text-2

I want to key bind save all to ctrl+alt+S. I know this has been asked and answered on the sublimelime text forum but it's currently down for me.

Does anyone remember how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have any other custom key bindings, click on `Preferences -> Key Bindings-User` and add the following to the empty file:

```json
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+s"], "command": "save_all" }
]
```

If you already have custom bindings, leave out the square brackets `[]`, and make sure you have a comma `,` after every binding but the last one.

Answer (score 1):

You must check first default key bindings so the new one doesn't override the defaults ones, for that reason is recommended to add this to the JSON file instead:

```
[
 {....},
 {....}
 //UP TO HERE IS WHAT YOU SHOULD HAVE, SO YOU HAVE TO ADD A COMMA ,
 // AND THEN THE KEY BINDING LIKE
 ,{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+shift+s"], "command": "save_all" }
]
```

Every {} set must have a comma (`,`) at the end, except for the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Save-All doesn't have default key binding in ST3 as well. When I press Ctrl+S I like to save all instead of current file. So I changed my key bindings as below.

Open Prefrences > KeyBindings-User and add following two lines:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+alt+s"], "command": "save" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+s"], "command": "save_all" }
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> > <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> works in Windows (Sublime Text 3) with no custom key bindings, etc.  You're simply using the keyboard to invoke the menu: File | Save All.

(Don't know about ST2 or other OS platforms)